Should unregistered users be allowed to post new questions?
I see that English Language & Usage has recently stopped unregistered users from posting new questions.

[Allowing unregistered users to ask questions] has led to many, many issues. Just a few of these are complete abandonment of questions without ever any further engagement from the poster, orphaned migrations to other sites, the moderation team not being able to contact the user, a steady stream of low-quality questions from users currently blocked for the same in their main account using throwaway unregistered accounts, and being an easy spam target.

All of these reasons would seem to apply here too. Should History SE follow suit and have the moderators ask that this be implemented here?

One piece of info on this: I seriously doubt this will even slow down our most committed troll much. However, it might be one hurdle too many for lesser trolls.

Also, I wish I had time to do this myself, but it might be useful to figure out how often "bad" (closed? deleted?) and "good" (multi-upvotes and good answers) questions are posted by unregistered users. I'm a big believer in making data-driven decisions.

List of sites which require registration can be found here: Why are unregistered users not allowed to post questions on some sites? (Some sites require registration only for asking questions. Some of them for answering, too.)
